# Use Samsung smart-scroll feature in my own app

Tags: android, scroll, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

Newer Samsung phones are providing extra features like multi-window support and smart-scroll.  I know that you can add multi-window support to an app by changing the manifest file.  Is there a similar way to do this for the smart-scroll feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to use the Samsung Mobile SDK for hand gesture support.

Comment: I'll check it out and report back

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the samsung mobile sdk, so it looks like I might be out of luck.  I did find an article which said "There's no word on whether this feature will be incorporated into an SDK eventually for third-party developers, but we're optimistic about it", http://www.engadget.com/2013/04/24/samsung-galaxy-s-4-review/.  So I might just have to wait.

Comment: @pickle_inspector: "I couldn't find anything in the samsung mobile sdk, so it looks like I might be out of luck" -- they covered it in the Samsung Developer Conference earlier this week. It is part of their Motion package, though they do not mention it on the site: http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk#motion